# VHDL - Do Functions used only in the architecture header take up FPGA logic?

Tags: compilation, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

If I have some code like so:

```
...

architecture behaviour of ExampleEntity is
  -- type definitions
  type Matrix is array(0 to 1,0 to 1) of signed(NumOfBitsForSignals_1 downto 0);

  -- function definitions

  function TransposeMatrix(MatrixArg : Matrix) return Matrix is  
      -- variable decleration   
      variable Result : Matrix; 
  begin  
    -- behaviour
    for columnNo in Result'range loop 
      for rowNo in Result'range loop    
        Result(columnNo, rowNo) := MatrixArg(rowNo, columnNo); 
      end loop;                                                                   
    end loop;
    return Result; 
  end function;
  -- constant definitions


  constant A00 : std_logic_vector(NumOfBitsForSignals_1 downto 0) := "A00Value";
  constant A01 : std_logic_vector(NumOfBitsForSignals_1 downto 0) := "A01Value";
  constant A10 : std_logic_vector(NumOfBitsForSignals_1 downto 0) := "A10Value";
  constant A11 : std_logic_vector(NumOfBitsForSignals_1 downto 0) := "A11Value";
  constant A : Matrix := ((signed(A00), signed(A01)),                                   

  constant A_Transpose : Matrix := TransposeMatrix(A);

...
```

And the TransposeMatrix function is only used once in this place is this function still synthesised or will the compiler assign the appropriate value to A_Transpose and remove this function from the synthesis? If this isn't the case and it synthesised the transpose function would it be better to remove this function and transpose the matrix manually and enter it?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.4.2.2 Constant declarations, *para 3* "If the assignment symbol “:=” followed by an expression is present in a constant declaration, the expression specifies the value of the constant; the type of the expression shall be that of the constant. The value of a constant cannot be modified after the declaration is elaborated."  A_Transpose is globally static, see 9.4 Static expressions, 9.4.1, 9.4.2 - e) the TransposeMatrix(A) call is not locally static, 9.4.3 - i), but is a pure function call with globally static parameters.  No logic involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, a synthesis tool will try it's very best to reduce the complexity of the generated net list. This includes working out the results of functions that have constant inputs, even if these inputs are themselves generated by other functions, depend on `generic` parameters, etc. The tools are so good at this process, that a simple mistake in your code can lead to whole parts of your design being optimised away.

That being the case, it doesn't actually matter whether the function is only called in a declarative region; no matter where a function is called, any simplifications or optimisations possible will be carried out by the synthesis tool.

Some tools do have limitations, for example if your function reads from files, or in some scenarios if it contains a loop with bounds that are determined by parameters. However, this will tend to result in either an error or a warning, as opposed to extra logic in the net list.